# Messages on chat app are only fetched for authenticated users while the other ones get an error

Tags: java, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to create a live chat app using NextJS, GraphQL and Apollo. I have a MessageList component which should display the most recent messages on the chat. Inside this component's code is :

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GetRecentMessagesQuery, {
    variables: {
      last: 100,
    },
  });
```

GetRecentMessagesQuery is defined by :

```
const GetRecentMessagesQuery = gql`
  query GetRecentMessages($last: Int) @live {
    messageCollection(last: $last) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          username
          avatar
          body
          likes
          createdAt
  }}}}
`
```

And the MessageList component will return a different JSX depending on the values of loading and error :

```
if (loading)
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-full">
        <p className="text-white">Fetching most recent chat messages.</p>
      </div>
    );

  if (error) {
    return (
      <p className="text-white">Something went wrong. Refresh to try again.</p>
    );
  }

  return (
    // Display the messages
```

The app allows the user to log in using GitHub, and if they do it the messages are displayed as they should. However unauthenticated users get the error and the messages are not displayed. I tried to log the error and it says "Apollo Error : Missing Data". I've been blocked by this for days as I have no idea where this could be coming from. I can share more code if needed. Thanks

Comment: Look at the query resolver code on the server for `GetRecentMessages` - it likely depends on the `context` being authorized.